# How to retrieve data from two different activity and show in another different activity

Tags: android, android-intent

How exactly I can retrieve data from two different (lets say : A and B) activities and I want to show in another activity (activity C). Maybe I can draw like this - A and B contains data which should be shown in C. Just simple like that.

**But the problem is when I receive data from A after that I take data from B (this time I am also receiving data from B). Data from A is missing or just like 'reset'. This problem also exists when I receive data from B and I take data from A.**

I am using below code :

Activity A : This how i sent Data using Intent

```
public static final String EXTRA_COUNTRY_SITE = "EXTRA_COUNTRY_SITE";
private static final int REQUEST_RESPONSE_SITE = 1;

class ItemLists implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView tvs = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSiteName);
     // Lets say textview just like String "Data A"
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LoginActivityView.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COUNTRY_SITE, tvs.getText().toString());
     // tvs.getText().toString() here you can change it to String
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_RESPONSE_SITE);
    }
}
```

Activity B : This how i sent Data using Intent

```
public static final String EXTRA_COUNTRY_EMPLOYEE = "EXTRA_COUNTRY_EMPLOYEE";
private static final int REQUEST_RESPONSE_EMPLOYEE = 1;

class ItemListe implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView tve = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmpName);
     // Lets say textview just like String "Data B"
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LoginActivityView.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COUNTRY_EMPLOYEE, tve.getText().toString());
     // tvs.getText().toString() here you can change it to String
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_RESPONSE_EMPLOYEE);
    }
}
```

Activity C : I just want to show in EditText

// Here this problem came from

```
    String country_emp = getIntent().getStringExtra(ViewEmployeeActivity.EXTRA_COUNTRY_EMPLOYEE);
    EditText editTextEmployee= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmployee);
    editTextEmployee.setText(country_emp);

    String country_site = getIntent().getStringExtra(ViewSiteActivity.EXTRA_COUNTRY_SITE);
    EditText editTextSite= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSite);
    editTextSite.setText(country_site);
```

And this is how I am going to activity A and B from activity C

```
    public void click(View v) {
    Intent intent = null;
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.editTextSite:
            intent = new Intent(this, ViewSiteActivity.class);
            break;
        case R.id.editTextEmployee:
            intent = new Intent(this, ViewEmployeeActivity.class);
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Any idea to solve that problem or another trick to pass data. Sorry for my bad english, I am just beginner for Android.

Comment: Using intents to pass data is an OK way to share data across activities.  What is your exact workflow?  If you are going from `A -> B -> C` then you would need to pass data via intents in this order.

Comment: my workflow is A & B -> C just this

Comment: There is no A&B ... you hop from one activity to another in Android.  Just pass the data you need across activities using intents.

Comment: But still activity C must get Data from both off them. If not like that it must be like this C -> A -> C-> B or C -> B -> C -> A. When C-> A -> C (I have data A) but when I start C -> B (I carrying data B) then I am back to C in here my data A is restored. So if B have data to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Shared Preferences to store the data and use them later on,
Here's the example

**To Store the data in the shared preferences**

1) **In Activity A**

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(EXTRA_COUNTRY_SITE,tvs.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
```

2) **In Activity B**

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(EXTRA_COUNTRY_EMPLOYEE,tvs.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
```

3) **In Activity C** use them

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String countrySite = prefs.getString(EXTRA_COUNTRY_SITE, null);
String countryEmp = prefs.getString(EXTRA_COUNTRY_EMPLOYEE, null);
```

Comment: thanks dude thats awesome, solve my problem. I wish i can upvote your answer. :D XD

Answer (score 0):

If C receive only from B and B only from  A then add the bundle receiving from A to the Intent starting C in B

```
Activity B
...
intent.putExtras(receivingBundle):
...
```

If you want to start Activity C from  A or B,
 C only receives the data from the starting Activity.

Comment: i start activity from C first, then i start activity A or B. Here my workflow if still confusing or i confusing to explain it. Data from A & B -> C.

Answer (score 0):

I understood this as, You want to pass data from A to B, then data of A and B to C. If this is so , you have to sent both A and B data from B to C. But you are sending only B data, as i can see code.

Try this in your B activity click event

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView tve = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmpName);
 // Lets say textview just like String "Data B"
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), LoginActivityView.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_COUNTRY_EMPLOYEE, tve.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra(ViewEmployeeActivity.EXTRA_COUNTRY_EMPLOYEE, getIntent().getStringExtra(ViewEmployeeActivity.EXTRA_COUNTRY_EMPLOYEE));
 // tvs.getText().toString() here you can change it to String
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_RESPONSE_EMPLOYEE);
}
```

Correct me if i understood your question wrong.

Comment: I mean i want recieve both data from a and b not a or b. Then pass in to Activity C...

Comment: Then maintain two public static strings for A and B activities and set data to strings after onclick events in respective activities. Then you can access both A and B strings from C Activity.

Comment: Just add this line in your onclick event in B activity, this will solve your requirement i guess
  
  intent.putExtra(ViewEmployeeActivity.EXTRA_COUNTRY_EMPLOYEE, getIntent().getStringExtra(ViewEmployeeActivity.EXTRA_COUNTRY_EMPLOYEE));

Comment: that not Solve my problem, when i alredy get data From A and i take data from B back to C nothing filled in my both edittext.